# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (68, 50, 50, 50, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a convolutional network that will work on a 3D voxel grid.  I try to add a fully connected layer but get an error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (68, 50, 50, 50, 1)

How can this be happening when I have a flatten layer first?  Shouldn't my input to the dense layer at that point be, well, flat?

```
x, y = load_data(directory)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution3D(1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu',
                        border_mode='same', name='conv1',
                        input_shape=(50, 50, 50, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32))
model.compile(
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
    )
model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    )
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1 (Conv3D)               (None, 50, 50, 50, 1)     28        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3 (None, 25, 25, 25, 1)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 15625)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32)                500032    
=================================================================
```

Comment: What's the shape of your output data?

Comment: You're right - flatten should make it 1D. Can we see some more of your code? e.g. everything from here to when you try to compile. Just FYI, having >15,000 fully connected neurons in your first layer is way too many - it will add 25 * 25 * 25* 15625 parameters which is 234 million just in that layer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, everyone!  I updated the post with more details and reduced the size of the dense layer

Comment: What's the shape of your Y ?

Comment: `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_test_split ....`

Answer (score 0):

`train_test_split` method split arrays into train and test set. If input to the method are list of arrays, the methods returns train and test tuples.

```py
train_set, test_set = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
x_train, y_train = train_set
x_test, y_test = test_set
```

or since python support left side assignment to tuples,

```py
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```